# jQuery array object to print only message key

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

> I have this response from the server how do i print only the message
>   at the $('#message') div
>   the response was json_encoded php

```
{
  "status":false,
  "message":"<div id='errmsg' class='alert alert-danger'><button type='button' class='btn btn-info pull-right' id='remove'>Remove<\/button><p> Username Is Required<\/p>\n<p> Password Is Required<\/p>\n<p> Name Is Required<\/p>\n<p> Designation Is Required<\/p>\n<\/div>"
}
```

this is my axax code that im using  iv

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#userform").submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var url = $(this).attr('action');
      var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
      $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data:  formData, 
           processData: false,
           contentType: false,
           success: function(data)
             {
               console.log(data);
               $('#message').html(data.message);                   
             }
         });
});
</script>
```

I keep getting undefined if I try `data['message']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to pass `dataType:'json'` in ajax request option, so jQuery automatically convert JSON string into JSON object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#userform").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr('action');
var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data:  formData, 
            processData: false,
        dataType: 'json',
           success: function(data)
           {
            console.log(data);
             $('#message').html(data.message);                     
           }
         });
});
</script>
```

Comment: hahaha...thanks i knew i deleted something important .....im just to fried right now i dint see the line missing  i'll accept your answer in 10 mins

Comment: @ReubenGomes, now time is completed ;)